# Jenkins searches in wrong artifactory path and build fails but local build is successful

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory, aar

we do have a Jenkins server and an Artifactory repository. We have published several libraries to that artifactory repo and it works well. We have also published the anyline sdk as an aar-module. In our projects we reference the artifactory-repo and the aar-module as such:

```
dependencies { ... compile 'anyline:anyline:3.6.1@aar' ... }     

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    // External Third Party Libs lookup
    maven {
        url "https://MYURL/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local"
        credentials {
            username = bla
            password = blubb
        }
    }
    // External Third Party Libs lookup
    maven {
        url "https://MYURL/artifactory/libs-release-local"
        credentials {
            username = bla
            password = blubb
        }
    }
    // External Third Party Libs lookup
    maven {
        url "https://MYURL/artifactory/ext-release-local"
        credentials {
            username = bla
            password = blubb
        }
    }
}
```

The url for the aar-package is this:

```
https://MYURL/artifactory/ext-release-local/anyline/anyline/3.6.1/anyline-3.6.1.aar
```

Locally the build just runs fine but on the jenkins it throws the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 
* What went wrong: 
A problem occurred configuring project ':BLABLUBB_app'. 
> Could not find anyline.jar (anyline:anyline:3.6.1). 
Searched in the following locations: 
https://MYURL/artifactory/libs-release-local/anyline/anyline/3.6.1/anyline-3.6.1.jar
```

Now there are two weird things going on here:

1.) Why does the jenkins-build look up a jar-file? Isn't it supposed to look up an aar-file or am I missing something?

2.) The server seems to search in the wrong folder. It should also search in 
    **ext-release-local**
and not only in 
    **libs-release-local**  where obviously no anyline-lib is located.

Does anyone have a hint on whats going wrong here?
The build script on the server is the same as the local one of course, the local repo and the server point to the same git.

Help appreciated,

Thanks
Daniel Sahm

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of jenkins configuration from UI.

Comment: Hello, of course. I am only not sure which configuration screen exactly you mean. Do you mean the configuration of the build-job? Thanks!